# Prime $4n+3$ simple proof?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p=4n+3$ be a prime.
Prove that $\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(x+k^2)\equiv (x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1)^2\pmod p$.

Is there a simple proof that doesn't use say arithmetic in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

My approach was to let $\text{LHS}=x^{p-1}+a_{p-2}x^{p-2}\cdots +a_1x+a_0$. It is easy to see that $a_0=((p-1)!)^2\equiv 1$ by Wilson's Theorem. If we can prove that $p\mid a_k$ for $k\in \{p-2,p-3,...,a_1\}$ barring $a_{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ (which apparently $p$ doesn't divide), then it will follow that $\text{LHS}\equiv x^{p-1}+a_{\frac{p-1}{2}}x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1$. It is therefore sufficient to show that $a_{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv 2\pmod p$, which seems hard to show directly using simple tools. Maybe we can use Vieta's formulae for the relation between the coefficients and roots of a polynomial, since the roots of $\text{LHS}$ are $-1^2,-2^2,...,-(p-1)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Two polynomials of degree $\leq p-1$ are equal in $\mathbb{Z}/p$ if and only if they have the same roots.  So it is sufficient to show that the residues of $-1^2, -2^2, \ldots , -(p-1)^2$ are exactly the residues $a$ with $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, each with multiplicity $2$.

Since $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv -1$ if and only if $a$ is not a square$\pmod{p}$, this comes down to showing that $-k^2$ is not a square$\pmod{p}$, which in turn follows from the fact that $-1$ is not a square$\pmod{p}$.

Comment: @Ark $\Bbb Z_p$ is a field and we can prove that two polynomials are equal if they have the same roots counted with multiplicities (the same degree follows) and the same dominant coefficient, because we can use the factorization $P=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)$

Comment: @Ark The main point here is that if $P$ and $Q$ are equal as functions, then $P-Q$ has the $p$ roots $0,1,\ldots,p-1$.  This implies that either $P-Q$ is the zero polynomial, or else has degree at least $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ P(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(x+k^2)$
we have $$P(-x^2)=\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(k^2-x^2)=\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(x-k)\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(x+k)=\left(\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(x-k)\right)^2$$

and because $\Bbb Z_p$ is a field, and the polynomial $x^{p-1}-1$ have exactly the $p-1$ roots $1,2,\cdots,p-1$ its factorization would be $x^{p-1}-1=\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(x-k)$ so we can conclude that $p(-x^2)=(x^{p-1}-1)^2$ hence $P(x)=\left(x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1\right)^2$